# Best way to for .htaccess temporary redirect (302) with exception

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-302

I am performing an update to a site and so I want to create a 302 temporary redirection for all webpages with the exception of one specific page.

perishablepress.com has two articles on the topic for which I am currently using option 1:

1. http://perishablepress.com/temporary-site-redirect-for-visitors-during-site-updates/
2. http://perishablepress.com/htaccess-redirect-maintenance-page-site-updates/

These article refer to amending all pages, where as I have one page I want to keep live. (As it goes I'm struggling to get option 2 to work at all). Can anyone tell me what is the best way to achieve this?

To clarify I would like to:

1. Have all pages redirect to `coming-soon.html` (i.e. *www.mywebsite.com/sample-page.html* => *www.mywebsite.com/coming-soon.html*)
2. Add an exception for `/contact-us.html` so that this request is processed normally  (i.e. `www.mywebsite.com/contact-us.html` => *www.mywebsite.com/contact-us.html*)

Comment: ¿That applies to all files or only to `.html` files.?

Comment: Ah! It would just be the site pages, so yes only the `.html` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !contact-us.html  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !coming-soon.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  \.(html|htm)/?    [NC]
RewriteRule .*  coming-soon.html              [R=301,L]
```